# Multiple Form with Single Submit Button

Tags: django, django-forms, multiple-forms

I'm currently working with django project. I had to filter the data store on the database based on the user input on form (at template) as looked below.

[image]

On form user either enter value or leave it blank. So what I have to do is first find the (valid) user input and then fire appropriate query to display data as user input in the form. So final result should be displayed on table at template.

As I'm new to django, how should I have to pass the data and fire query to represent data at multiple field. As help or link related to these type problem are expected. ( I just able to filter from the database with only one form and had no concept to solve this.)

Model of my temp project is as below.

```
class exReporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    label = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Can you please maybe explain what you want to do by using example input/output. Your problem description is not clear enough.

Comment: You may want to rethink your title.  It says "multiple forms" but I think you have one form with multiple optional fields, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you can take, but here is one solution you can use that involves chaining together the appropriate filters based on the form's posted data:

*Note: To conform to Python's naming convention, rename *exReporter* class to *ExReporter*.

```
# views.py
def process_ex_reporter_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ExReporterForm implementation details not included.
        ex_reporter_form = ExReporterForm(request.POST)

        if ex_reporter_form.is_valid():
            # If form field has no data, cleaned data should be None.
            gender = ex_reporter_form.cleaned_data['gender']
            age_start = ex_reporter_form.cleaned_data['age_start']
            age_end = ex_reporter_form.cleaned_data['age_end']
            aggregation_group = ex_reporter_form.cleaned_data['aggregation_group']
            aggregation_id = ex_reporter_form.cleaned_data['aggregation_id']

            ex_reporters = ExReporter.objects.get_ex_reporters(gender, age_start,
                               age_end, aggregation_group, aggregation_id)

        else:
            # Pass back form for correction.
            pass

    else:
        # Pass new form to user.
        pass

# models.py
class ExReporterManager(models.Manager):
    def get_ex_reporters(self, gender, age_start, age_end, aggregation_group,
                         aggregation_id):

        ex_reporters = super(ExReporterManager, self).get_query_set().all()

        # Even though the filters are being applied in separate statements,
        # database will only be hit once.
        if ex_reporters:
            if gender:
                ex_reporters = ex_reporters.filter(gender=gender)

            if age_start:
                ex_reporters = ex_reporters.filter(age__gt=age_start)

            if age_end:
                ex_reporters = ex_reporters.filter(age__lt=age_end)

            # Apply further filter logic for aggregation types supported.

        return ex_reporters
```